# Send an SMS when an item is purchased in Prestashop

Tags: php, api, module, sms, prestashop

I am using Prestashop. I would like to send an SMS when a user purchases an item. Could I use the Mvaayoo SMS integration API? How?

This is my PHP code to send an SMS:

```
<?php 
    $ch = curl_init();
    $user="emailid@example:password;
    $receipientno="9995563285"; 
    $senderID="TEST SMS"; 
    $msgtxt="this is test message , test"; 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,  "http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageCompose");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=$user&senderID=$senderID&receipientno=$receipientno&msgtxt=$msgtxt");
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    if(empty ($buffer))
    { echo " buffer is empty "; }
    else
    { echo $buffer; } 
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Placing API code for each events like User registration, new order, order status change will be heavy.

You can use any Free SMS Add-on like Spring Edge [Prestashop sms add-on](https://www.springedge.com/prestashop-sms-extension-module-free.html) which will make your way easy.

Just need to install and configure events from Admin-Area:

- SMS on Order confirmation.
- SMS on Order shipment.
- SMS on User Registration.